# Consumer is receiving only 50 percent of the messages published to the topic

Tags: apache-pulsar

We're noticing that exactly 50 percent of the messages produced to my Pulsar topic are reaching my app. Everything was working fine yesterday where our Pulsar consumer app was getting 100% of messages that were produced to the topic. We haven't made any setting changes in our app. What is happening with the missing messages? Where are they going?

Comment: I see plenty of content when I google `devin bost pulsar`.  Do you have some direct affiliation with Pulsar or just an enthusiastic user/advocate?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm an Apache Pulsar (open source) contributor. (I have no paid affiliation with the open-source technology.) Notice that I answered my own question to provide guidance to individuals who experience this issue since the cause is rather specific.

Comment: Your contributions gained the attention of some content curators in a chat room and I thought I would ask about your affiliation -- in case there was a need for you to disclose it.  Thanks for replying.  (I have absolutely no knowledge of Apache Pulsar, so I am not in any position to combat the no-comment dv's on your question) (I had no-comment dv's and I cop my fair share of these -- mostly on my questions, not my answers.)

Comment: @mickmackusa What about my contributions gained their attention?

Comment: I don't remember specifically (and I don't have the energy to go hunting in the backlogs), but it was concerned with whether or not there was some form of self-promotion going on.

Answer (score 1):

Pulsar isn't losing your messages.

It looks like you're using a shared subscription and more than one consumer connected. That other consumer is receiving your other messages since the topic will dispatch them in a round-robin when using a shared subscription. This behavior can occur by design if your consumers are auto-scaling on a shared subscription.

If you check topic stats (`$ pulsar-admin topics stats options`, [documented here](https://pulsar.apache.org/tools/pulsar-admin/2.8.0-SNAPSHOT/#-em-stats-em--42)), in the response, in "subscriptions", look for your subscription by its name. In that object, you can see the "type", which will be marked as "shared," and you will see a list of "consumers". I'd expect that you have more than one consumer in that list.